# Encrypt text using Security.Cryptography on ironpython

Tags: python, .net, encryption, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I am trying to make encryption work on sharpdevelop using IronPython to encrypt text but I am getting the error below:

"Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm."

I tried using all three encodings, tried different size for the key like 128, 256, 1024 and nothing.

This is the code I am using:

```
import System.Security.Cryptography
from System.Text import UTF8Encoding, ASCIIEncoding, UnicodeEncoding

self.MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
self.DES = System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider()
self.UTF8Encode = UTF8Encoding()
self.ASCIIEncode = ASCIIEncoding()
self.Unicode = UnicodeEncoding()

def MD5Hash(self, value):
    return self.MD5.ComputeHash(self.Unicode.GetBytes(value))

def Encrypt(self, StringInput, Key):
    self.DES.Key = self.MD5Hash(Key)
    DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB()
    buffer = self.UTF8Encode.GetBytes(StringInput)
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(self.DES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, len(buffer)))

def Button1Click(self, sender, e):
    self._textBox2.Text = self.Encrypt(self._textBox1.Text, 'keys')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DES is not triple DES. DES is a block cipher with a 64 bit block size and a key size of 56 bits, usually represented as 64 bits where one bit of each byte is parity. Of course, you should not be using DES anymore, you should be using AES instead. DES can be cracked in a very short time frame.

You should not be using MD5 or ECB either actually. Maybe you should read up on your cryptography before starting to code.

Comment: After your advice I was able to get it working using AES. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
import System.Security.Cryptography
from System.Text import ASCIIEncoding

self.AES = System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider()
self.ASCIIEncode = ASCIIEncoding()

def Encrypt(self, StringInput, key, salt):
    saltArray = self.ASCIIEncode.GetBytes(salt)
    rfcKey = System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltArray, 10000)
    self.AES.Key = rfcKey.GetBytes(self.AES.KeySize / 8)
    self.AES.IV = rfcKey.GetBytes(self.AES.BlockSize /8)
    buffer = self.ASCIIEncode.GetBytes(StringInput)
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(self.AES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))

def Decrypt(self, EncryptedString, key, salt):
    saltArray = self.ASCIIEncode.GetBytes(salt)
    rfcKey = System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltArray, 10000)
    self.AES.Key = rfcKey.GetBytes(self.AES.KeySize / 8)
    self.AES.IV = rfcKey.GetBytes(self.AES.BlockSize /8)
    buffer = System.Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedString)
    return self.ASCIIEncode.GetString(self.AES.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
```

Comment: Just a tip - rather than using MD5 for obtain the necessary bytes for the key (which is insecure), use something based on [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) instead. It's provided in .NET as the horribly-named [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: I changed and I am now using PBKDF2. Thanks Jeff Hardy